# List all running/queued threads in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, threadpool, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I use a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in Spring to schedule my tasks.

Is there a way to get a list or something of every running and queued thread of that task executor/pool?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? `getActiveCount()` returns the number of currectly active threads. `getPoolSize()` returns the number of threads in the pool. What do you need more? And why?

Comment: `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue()` states _Returns the task queue used by this executor. Access to the task queue is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring. This queue may be in active use. Retrieving the task queue does not prevent queued tasks from executing._

Comment: @JBNizet I want to know whats going on in my application ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe not very elegant, but this way I can get all threads from a known Executor (using the `startsWith()` prefix).

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
for (Thread thread : threadSet) {
  if (thread.getName().startsWith("MyExecutor")) {
  System.out.println(thread.getName() + " " + thread.getState());
    for (StackTraceElement s : thread.getStackTrace()) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to Surveon for his hint, I upvoted for his approch to get the queued threads.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can get at the underlying [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html?is-external=true) by calling [getThreadPoolExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#getThreadPoolExecutor%28%29).

This would allow you to access the queue, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use Reflection or Spring provided ReflectionUtils or ReflectionTestUtils..

I used ReflectionTestUtils in my Junit to test the scenario when one or more sleeping thread is interrupted.

The code snippet is:

```
Collection<Object> workers = (Collection<Object>) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(responseHandlerTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor(), "workers");

for(Object worker : workers){
    Thread workerThread = (Thread)ReflectionTestUtils.getField(worker, "thread");
    workerThread.interrupt();
}
```